# Moving data from Plone 4 to Plone 3

Tags: plone

Oddly enough, I'm looking towards moving the data I have added in Plone 4 into Plone 3.

Reason being, I've not been able to add the pdf_to_html transforms into P4, and I've tried everything. I used to use P3, and that indexed just fine, but no joy now.

Can anybody advise if this is possible?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Difficult at best. You'll need the blob support that was still an optional add-on, at the very least. (Personally, I'd throw half a week at fixing pdf_to_html before even considering moving back.)

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, I had a feeling that would be the case. I used an external pdftotxt program, which works perfectly when executed from the command line, but got a MIME malformed error when adding the transform to portal_transforms. Any thoughts?

Comment: please post the error and context. Are you on the same machine, for example?

Comment: Yuri, Plone is running on a VM (Windows server 2008). The general consensus is that I would need to add open office, and then an external pdf reader (I went with xpdf), and then add pdf_to_text as a transform, with the module: Products.PortalTransforms.transforms.pdf_to_text. When I add this I get the following: Module Products.MimetypesRegistry.MimeTypesRegistry, line 457, in split
MimeTypeException: Malformed MIME type (BROKEN)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I experienced the same error you did:

Module Products.MimetypesRegistry.MimeTypesRegistry, line 457, in split MimeTypeException: Malformed MIME type (BROKEN)

When adding the transform manually.

If however you blow away and recreate the plone portal object, the transform is created successfully.

Not a great solution, but might be useful.

Comment: I think the problem could be that you added the pdf_to_text later, and something went wrong with the portal transform. You can also try to recreate the transforms but there's something persistent to be aware of, you've to search on google to find out why :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on local.

This was because I didn't have the pdftotext binary install on my device.

On mac : `brew install poppler`